# Spring Boot Microservice - Call another microservice (500 Internal Error)

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak, spring-cloud

I have a problem about making any request from management service to user service.

When I tried to make a request to this url (`http://localhost:9002/api/v1/user_role/alladvertisements`), I got this issue shown below.

Here is my error in management service.

```
    org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException$InternalServerError: 500 : "{"timestamp":"2022-07-26T21:52:03.060+00:00","status":500,"error":"Internal Server 
Error","path":"/api/v1/users/info"}"
```

Here is my error shown in user service.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class org.keycloak.KeycloakPrincipal (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; org.keycloak.KeycloakPrincipal is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

I think there is a problem in rest template but I couldn't solve it.

How can I fix it?

Here is my project link : [Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/SpringBootMicroservices)

Here is UserController of management service

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/user_role")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserController {

    private final UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("/alladvertisements")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Advertisement>> getAllAdvertisements(){
        return ResponseEntity.ok(userService.getAllAdvertisements());
    }
}
```

Here is my UserServiceImpl of management service

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

private static final String USER_BASE_URL = "http://USER-SERVICE:9000/api/v1/users";
private final RestTemplate restTemplate;


private String getRoleInfo(){

        String result = this.restTemplate.getForObject(USER_BASE_URL + "/info",String.class);

        return result;
    }

}
```

Here is my Controller class shown below.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/user_role")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserController {

    private final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    private final UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("/alladvertisements")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Advertisement>> getAllAdvertisements(){

        LOGGER.info("UserController | getAllAdvertisements is started");

        return ResponseEntity.ok(userService.getAllAdvertisements());
    }
}
```

Here is my UserServiceImpl of management service

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

private static final String USER_BASE_URL = "http://USER-SERVICE:9000/api/v1/users";
private final RestTemplate restTemplate;


private String getRoleInfo(){

        String result = this.restTemplate.getForObject(USER_BASE_URL + "/info",String.class);

        return result;
    }

}
```

Here is my application properties file in api gateway shown below.

```
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=user-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=lb://user-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/api/**

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].id=management-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].uri=lb://management-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].predicates[0]=Path=/api/**
```

Here is my user controller of User service

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1/users")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserController {

@GetMapping("/info")
    public ResponseEntity<?> infoUser(){

}

}
```

Here is my infoUser method of Userservice

```
@GetMapping("/info")
    public ResponseEntity<?> infoUser(){

        LOGGER.info("UserController | infoUser is started");

        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        KeycloakPrincipal principal = (KeycloakPrincipal)auth.getPrincipal(); -> ISSUE IS HERE
        KeycloakSecurityContext session = principal.getKeycloakSecurityContext();
        AccessToken accessToken = session.getToken();

        String username = accessToken.getPreferredUsername();
        String email = accessToken.getEmail();
        String lastname = accessToken.getFamilyName();
        String firstname = accessToken.getGivenName();
        String realmName = accessToken.getIssuer();
        AccessToken.Access access = accessToken.getRealmAccess();
        Set<String> roles = access.getRoles();

        String role = roles.stream()
                .filter(s -> s.equals("ROLE_USER") || s.equals("ROLE_ADMIN"))
                .findAny()
                .orElse("noElement");

        LOGGER.info("UserController | infoUser | username : " + username);
        LOGGER.info("UserController | infoUser | email : " + email);
        LOGGER.info("UserController | infoUser | lastname : " + lastname);
        LOGGER.info("UserController | infoUser | firstname : " + firstname);
        LOGGER.info("UserController | infoUser | realmName : " + realmName);
        LOGGER.info("UserController | infoUser | firstRole : " + role);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(role);
    }
```

Comment: `auth.getPrincipal();` returns a `String`. How are you setting the Principal?

Comment: @CaptainPyscho When I call ```http://localhost:9000/api/v1/users/info``` in user service, I get ROLE_USER or ROLE_ADMIN. When I call getRole method from another service to reach out this method of user service, I get this issue. How can I fix it?

Comment: @CaptainPyscho I cannot still fix my issue.